# jQuery-File-Upload rails ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload, turbolinks

I am using Turbolinks in my rails project . When I clicked upload button(ajax call),it fails and the error section is showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. The same problem is showing with regular link(no ajax) which is caused by turbolinks I think because turbolinks uses ajax in the background.

my upload page's javascript:

```
<html>
..... html code ...

<%= javascript_include_tag 'js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "js/jquery.iframe-transport" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "js/jquery.fileupload.js" %>

<script>
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var filestoupload = 0;
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
         add: function(e, data) {
                if(data.files[0]['size'] > 20000000) {
                   $('#errors_append').html('maximum size for file allowed is 20 mb');
                } else {
                    data.submit();
                }
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                filestoupload++;
                $('').text(file.name + ' ' + 'uploaded successfully').appendTo('#files_append');

                if (filestoupload > 2) {
                  $('#file_button').attr("disabled","disabled");
                }
            });
            $("#btn_text").html('Add more files');
        },
        start: function (e, data) {
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                0 + '%'
                );   
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
                );
        },
        success: function(xhr){
          $('#progress .progress-bar').attr('class', 'progress-bar progress-bar-success');
          $('#errors_append').empty();      
      },
      error: function(xhr){
          var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).error
          $('#errors_append').html(errors);
          $('#progress .progress-bar').attr('class', 'progress-bar progress-bar-danger');        
      }
  }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
.parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

Comment: where is your `js/jquery.fileupload.js` file in your directory? and why are you using js in your view?

Comment: in /app/assets/javascripts/js/jquery.fileupload.js

Comment: can you post exact error that you are getting in your developer console

Comment: I'have added screenshots but i dont have enough reputaion point :( ,

Comment: the error is : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function and it's occurring in jquery.fileupload.js in line 63 ($.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {)

Comment: I think you are using it wrong way then, need to check how it works though and by the way you should use rails asset pipeline and include your js files there and also avoid using js inside views

Comment: No , but when i remove turbolinks, it works fine, or when i'have included the js in application.js(require) it works also fine even with turbolinks. But currently i dont know exactly why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got `jquery-file-upload` working with `ajax` [here](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com) (sign up for account then try updating your profile pic). Model is [Veronica Crespo](https://twitter.com/veritocrespo):

[image]

--

**Turbolinks**

The main issue with Turbolinks is that it will prevent your on-page JS from loading the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) elements it requires.

Because Turbolinks just refreshes the `<body>` element of your page (not the `<head>`), JS still thinks that it's in the "old" state, preventing it from picking up any of the newly-loaded elements.

Its fixed by either [`delegating`](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) your JS from a constant element (typically `document`), or by using the [`Turbolinks event` hooks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to fix it:

```
var load = function() {
   ...
};

$(document).on("page:load ready", load);
```

--

**Fix**

In regards to working with Turbolinks, here's the code we used for the Avatar functionality in one of our demo apps:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$('#avatar').fileupload({

    url: '/profile/' + $(this).attr('data_id'),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',

    add: function (e, data) {
        //$(".items .avatar .avatar").prepend('<div class="loading" id="avatar_loading"><img src="<%= asset_path("profile/avatar_loading.gif") %>"></div>');
        //$('#avatar_loading').fadeIn('100');
        $(this).avatar_loading('avatar_loading');
        data.submit();
    },
    success: function (data, status) {;
        $("#avatar_img").fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).attr("src", data.avatar_url).fadeIn('fast', function(){
                $(this).avatar_loading('avatar_loading');
            });
        });
    }

});
```

This is in line with the `jquery-fileupload` gem:

```
#Gemfile
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails", "~> 0.4.1"

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```